# Predicting color and opponent

Tags: tournament, planning, swiss-pairing

Is there any way to predict, with some certainty, my next opponent and color for next round in a swiss tournement on chess-result:
http://chess-results.com/tnr406767.aspx?lan=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sure-fire way is for you to buy your own copy of [Swiss Manager](http://swiss-manager.at/), the pairing software used in this particular case, and reproduce the tournament and then do the next round pairing once all the results are in. The light version of Swiss Manager, which you could use since there are fewer than 60 players, costs 75 euros.

Alternatively you could try and do the pairing by hand yourself. For this you would need to read, understand and follow the [FIDE Swiss rules](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=18&view=category) for pairing.

Comment: That will usually work, although I wouldn't *quite* call it "sure-fire"; withdrawals or half-point byes might trip you up if you aren't aware of which players requested them.

Comment: @DM Indeed and for many tournaments if you look at the first round pairings with an experienced arbiter's eye you can see much that needs to be explained (by late withdrawals, forbidden pairings, etc.) On both sides of the draw the player start rankings for both odd and even pairings should go up by 2 each time. Withdrawals and half point bye information is available on chess-results under "not paired". Here is the page for the Gibraltar Masters - http://chess-results.com/tnr377792.aspx?lan=1&art=40. If this is uptodate for your tournament then you can use it. No need to trip up.